# send extras to broadcast reciever from Activity

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

My application is about Reminders. After inserting the reminders into the SQLite database it is showing ID's correctly in the AddReminderActivity.java class correctly but it is returning ID=1 in the AlarmReciver.java class in the following code.

This is how I am putting extra

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("reminderId", reminderId);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 5, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    assert mAlarmManager != null;
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliSecondsFromDate, pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set at " + selectedDate + " " + timeInHrs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
```

This is how i am getting extra

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Long reminderId = intent.getLongExtra("reminderId", -1);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    Reminder reminder = mDatabaseHelper.getReminder(reminderId);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TTSService.class);
    if (reminder != null && !reminder.getText().isEmpty()) {
        serviceIntent.putExtra("reminderText", reminder.getText());
    }
    context.startService(serviceIntent);

    Toast.makeText(context, "AlarmReciever..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This to getting extra

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Long reminderId = intent.getExtras().getLong("reminderId", -1);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    Reminder reminder = mDatabaseHelper.getReminder(reminderId);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TTSService.class);
    if (reminder != null && !reminder.getText().isEmpty()) {
        serviceIntent.putExtra("reminderText", reminder.getText());
    }
    context.startService(serviceIntent);

    Toast.makeText(context, "AlarmReciever..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: This code is functionally equivalent to the original code that was posted. This code will execute exactly the same as the original code. This will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the "extras" to be set correctly, you need to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in the call to `getBroadcast()` as follows:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 5, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Also, are you sure that `reminderId` is of type `long` or `Long` in the code where you call `putExtra()`?

Comment: Great! If my answer was helpful, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will give us both some reputation points and remove the question from the list of unanswered questions. It may also help someone else in the future who has a similar problem.